# SIngle value into array from form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have a registration form which collects dates a user wants to register for an event. Using checkboxes, a user can select multiple dates which are then added to an array in the `formObject`. To write the values to a Google sheet, I check the length of the array of dates and then loop so individual rows are added to the spreadsheet.

I'm having a hard time forcing the `class` key to *always* be an array, even if it's a single class. If only one class is selected, the `length` property is the length of the string, writing 9 or 10 rows of data with single characters.

**Form**

```html
<form id="classSignup" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  <label for="first">First Name</label>
  <input id="first" name="first" type="text" />
  <label for="last">Last Name</label>
  <input id="last" name="last" type="text"  />
  <input type='checkbox' name='class' value='date1'>Date 1</input>
  <input type='checkbox' name='class' value='date2'>Date 2</input>
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

**formObject**

```
{last=lastName, first=firstName, class=[dateArray]}
```

**recordData**

```js
function recordData(formObject) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("allRegs");
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
    var rows = [ ];

    // check the formObject structure
    Logger.log(formObject);

    // Open the class array
    for(var i=0; i<formObject.class.length; i++) {

      // set the date with the current item
        var date = formObject.class[i];
        Logger.log(date);

        var row = [new Date(), formObject[headers[1]], formObject[headers[2]], formObject[headers[3]], formObject[headers[4]], formObject.class[i]]

        rows.push(row);
  } // close the rows loop

    // write the rows array to the spreadsheet
}
```

Above, if `date1` and `date2` are selected, an array is returned and everything works as normal:

```js
{ first=firstName, last=lastName, class=[date1, date2] }
```

When a single date is selected, there is no array, just a string in `formObject`:

```js
{ first=firstName, last=lastName, class=date1 }
```

How can I force any class selected to be pushed into an array?

Comment: where's the code which populates `formObject`? why not just always pass `class` as an array (`class=[date1]`)?

Comment: The `formObject` is built with a Google Apps Script function. I tried returning the form with the class as an array, but it is treated as a string, not as an array.

Comment: you could test the `typeof formObject.class` before your `for` loop, and if its a string make it an array containing the string

Comment: OK, that did it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `class` to `class[]` to force it into an array

Answer (score 0):

Create a class array outside your loop then push to it inside the loop.
THEN create your "row" object since as I see it you have one "row" in the "rows" given your form.

Note I do not fully understand your "rows" array as the form is a single form here.

```
function recordData(formObject) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("allRegs");
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var rows = [];
    var classes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < formObject.class.length; i++) {
      classes.push[formObject.class[i]];
    }
    // set the date with the current item
    // was not used... var date = formObject.class[i];
    // Logger.log(date);
    var row = [new Date(), formObject[headers[1]], formObject[headers[2]], formObject[headers[3]], formObject[headers[4]], classes];
    rows.push(row);// seems to be only one?
  }
  // whatever here.
)
```

Comment: I might not have been clear enough. When it's a single checkbox, it is added to `class` as a string, not as an array with a `length` of 1. Multiple dates work fine, which is why I have  a `rows` array.